# Thunderbird Address Book Error On Start

Tags: 13.04, thunderbird, address-book

When I start Thunderbird (Version 17.0.7) in Ubuntu 13.04 I get the following notification -

[image: Thunderbird Error Message]

Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this?

Thanks

*Update for Bob*

Here are my installed add-ons, I believe it is all default except for adblock

[image]

Comment: can you post your add-ons you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, address book named personal is made from EDS. Please try to delete it and then in next start-up it will be re-created. On the other hand, you should have an other address book named Personal Address Book which is the "working" address book.

**Update**: Since this does not solve the problem, I propose to try and create an empty profile:

start TB with profile manager in terminal:

> thunderbird -profilemanager

Then create a new profile. In next screen give a name to the new profile and locate the folder for the profile. There you can point to new folder and then import any data from old profile you wish. But at this point, the problem of the EDS address book (personal) should be solved because it should be repopulated.

You can actually make more than one profiles for backing up purposes.

The address book file is located in your profile folder and is named abook.mab. You may decide to make a backup copy in an other directory.

**Update 2**: Re-install EDS. In Synaptics package manager, search for evolution, and re-install evolution-data-server-common, evolution-data-server, libebook-1.2-12, libedataserver-1.2-15, libedata-book-1.2-11 & gnome-contacts (if installed) packages

Comment: Both those entries are present, along with the 'Friends' address books. I select the delete option for Personal, it asks if I am sure, I click OK then nothing happens. It has not populated with contacts but that is probably due to the error.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: That might have done it! At first I asked the new profile to use the 'default' folder, but the error came back again. So have set up a new profile with new folders and the error has not appeared on start. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Logged into Thunderbird today and the error has returned with the new Profile :-( Looks like I might just have to migrate to Evolution.

Comment: I am sorry to hear this. EDS is Evolution Data Service that is used by gnome (& unity) desktop in order to sync data with external services (like email, contacts with google, etc). I am afraid you will have similar problem with Evolution as well... An other idea came, see updated answer.

Comment: Installed Evolution but that error never came up. I did reinstall all the packages you suggested, but Thunderbird is still throwing up that message. Evolution seems to be working fine, my contacts lists is populated and no issues so far.